# How to share HTML/CSS across multiple web pages

Tags: php

I am new to programming, and have developed the main design features of my website and need to be able to share what I have done across multiple pages.  It is mostly HTML and CSS code, with a little java. I plan on using PHP next with MySQL next.  I have read about php include files, which seem pretty straight forward. My question is, are php include files the best way to go?  Or will this cause problems down the road?  What are common ways to work around this.

Thank you!

Comment: Don use php includes for outside resourves (javascript files, css, etc.), use a proper `<link>` / `<script>`, it saves both the user & your server bandwidth as those static files can be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use php include files. For the CSS, put it in a `css` folder, or any folder, then:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-css/style.css" />`